# Wordpress - displaying last posts custom way

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I'm new to wordpress. I have a task to display last 3 posts, but not with a usual way. Post divs will have different sizes. This is my html code.

```
<div class="latest-posts">
       <div class="latest-posts-news-left">NEWS</div>
       <div class="latest-posts-news-right">
           <div class="l">
               <div class="latest-posts-news-first">first post</div>
               <div class="latest-posts-news-second">second post</div>
           </div>
           <div class="r">
               <div class="latest-posts-news-third">third post</div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

This is the image to show you how it looks http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/5194/1n3u.png

So two divs at left and one longer div at right.

How should i loop i this case? I would be very grateful if you will give me an working example, cause i was searching an answer, but didnt found.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you show your code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=5,orderby=post_date,order=DESC' );
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {

while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
$queryObject->the_post();
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=3,orderby=post_date,order=DESC' );
 ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 


        $count_rows  = 0;
?>

<div class="latest-posts">
       <div class="latest-posts-news-left">NEWS</div>
       <div class="latest-posts-news-right">

  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php if( ( $count_rows + 1 ) % 2 == 0 ) { ?>
     <div class="l">
               <div class="latest-posts-news-first"><?php the_post(); ?></div>
               <div class="latest-posts-news-second"><?php the_post(); ?></div>
           </div>
       <?php  } else { ?>

        <div class="r">
               <div class="latest-posts-news-third"><?php the_post(); ?></div>
           </div>
  <?php } 
  $count_rows++; 
  endwhile; ?>
  <!-- end of the loop -->

</div>
</div>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else:  ?>
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```